# creating list gives error when not enough data

Tags: php

creating list gives error when not enough data

**What I did:**

```
<?php
    $a=$b=$c=array();
    list($a,$b,$c) = array_chunk(array("A","B","C","D","E"), 3);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(array($a,$b,$c));
?>
```

getting error like:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/html/test.php on line 13
```

how to fix it?

in above case if there is no value then keep last array blank.

**How to devide data in 3 array ? and if there is no enough data then keep last array blank.**

Comment: Check if there is enough data before assigning to `list()`. Pad the array to a minimum length. Don't assign to individual variables in the first place and keep things in an array.

Comment: Your array_chunk should have the second argument as 2. It will divide the array into 3 arrays each containing 2 elements. If you try to divide it into 3 arrays each with 3 elements you'll get the error you're experiencing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list($a,$b,$c) = array_pad(array_chunk(array("A","B","C","D","E"), 3), 3, array());
```

If you are less elements in your array, array_pad will fill it with default value.

Answer (score 0):

The error is simply saying that offset is undefined. The list function is only getting 2 of them but as in code it needs three. So if you use this code it wont give you the error

```
<?php
    $a=$b=$c=array();
    list($a,$b) = array_chunk(array("A","B","C","D","E"), 3);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(array($a,$b,$c));
?>
```

Or if you chunk the array into two parts it will also work and will divide the array into three parts.

```
 <?php
        $a=$b=$c=array();
        list($a,$b) = array_chunk(array("A","B","C","D","E"), 2);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(array($a,$b,$c));
    ?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I know that but my question is how to divide data in 3 array, and if there is no enough data keep last array blank